# angular-meteor.auth resolve to a blank page

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to authenticate the user before the view, in this case `dashboard`, gets rendered.

If the user is logged in, then your good to go, but if not, redirect to `login` state.

This is my controller:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import angularMeteorAuth from 'angular-meteor-auth';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { name as navBar } from '../navBar/navBar';

import './dashboard.html';

class dashboardCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    'ngInject';

    if (Meteor.user()) {
      console.log('logged in ', Meteor.user());
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in or error');
    }
  }
}

const name = 'dashboard';

export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  navBar,
  angularMeteorAuth
])
  .component(name, {
    templateUrl: `imports/ui/components/${name}/${name}.html`,
    controller: dashboardCtrl,
  })
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      template: '<dashboard></dashboard>',
      resolve: {
        user: function($auth, $state){
          return $auth.requireUser().then(function(){
            return true;
          }, function(err){
            $state.go('login');
          });
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

This works fine if the user is not logged in, it will redirect to `login` normally, but when the user is indeed logged in and you try to refresh in `dashboard` it returns a blank screen/page with no console logs or errors or anything.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the user property in some way? You are just returning a boolean inside the promise.